# Wordpress Twenty Twelve Theme & Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

Preface: I am not a developer, but I was able to figure out enough about CSS to modify the twenty twelve theme for desktop browsers into this website: http://www.abcllc.org

Now that I have that looking the way I need it to, I've turned my attention to mobile. The theme has responsiveness built into it, but when I access the site from a mobile device, it scrunches it way up into the left side of the screen. Can I set a minimum width for mobile screens, or set it to auto-fill a mobile screen? The only thing I've figured out is the cutoff width between mobile and a regular browser (which I set to 640px).

I found varying threads throughout the interweb with people having the same issue, but with no answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just Search about media queries and Responsive Design

Answer (score 0):

You can check out mine and see if that helps.

http://www.fossfolks.com/

My site is by no means the best example of css and design, but there's a lot less going on and it might be easier to see.  There's a link to the stylesheet in the source.  My current struggle is getting images to resize (width AND height) based on a percentage of screen width; I've not been able to sit down long enough to make it go.